# Assigning Delegate to TreeView Cell

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview

Currently I'm creating a QTreeView where the 3rd column delegate is set to a ComboBox for editing. However I would like to give users the ability to toggle different views with the given data as seen in the images below. How would you recommend I handle the ComboBox being assigned to the correct row/colum for the specified cells as show in the images below?

The Flat List version works great, I'm not sure how to handle the other display option.

Is there a way to set the delegate that provides a QComboBox, as an editor, per row/column?

[image]

[image]

```
import os, sys, pprint
sys.path.append(os.environ.get('PS_SITEPACKAGES'))
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore   
import pprint

class VersionProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VersionProxyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)

    def checkParents(self, index):
        while (index.isValid()):
            if super(VersionProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(index.row(), index.parent()):
                return True
            index = index.parent()
        return False

    def checkChildren(self, index):
        for i in range(0, self.sourceModel().rowCount(index)):
            if super(VersionProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(i, index):
                return True

        # recursive
        for i in range(0, self.sourceModel().rowCount(index)):
            self.checkChildren(self.sourceModel().index(i, 0, index))

        return False 

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, parent):
        if super(VersionProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, parent):
            return True

        if self.checkChildren(self.sourceModel().index(source_row, 0, parent)):
            return True

        return self.checkParents(parent)


class ComboBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
             self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)
        super(ComboBoxDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent)
        editor.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.commitEditor)
        return editor

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def commitEditor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            self.parent().updateEditorGeometries()

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        values = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 100)
        val = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 101)
        editor.clear()
        for i, x in enumerate(values):
            editor.addItem(x['fullname'], x)
            if val['fullname'] == x['fullname']:
                editor.setCurrentIndex(i)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        values = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 100)
        ix = editor.currentIndex()
        model.setData(index, values[ix] , QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 101)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800, 400)

        self.FLATLIST = {   
            'Leslie': [
                    {'fullname': 'medic_skin_v001', 'entity': 'Medic', 'type': 'Bulky'}
                ],
            'Mike': [ 
                    {'fullname': 'tech_skin_v001', 'entity': 'Tech', 'type': 'Average'},
                    {'fullname': 'tech_skin_v002', 'entity': 'Tech', 'type': 'Average'}
                ],
            'Kevin': [ 
                    {'fullname': 'tech_skin_v001', 'entity': 'Tech', 'type': 'Average'},
                ],
            'Michelle': [
                    {'fullname': 'warrior_skin_v001', 'entity': 'Warrior', 'type': 'Athletic'},
                    {'fullname': 'warrior_skin_v002', 'entity': 'Warrior', 'type': 'Athletic'},
                    {'fullname': 'warrior_skin_v003', 'entity': 'Warrior', 'type': 'Athletic'}]
            }


        self.uiDisplayA = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Display Flat List')
        self.uiDisplayA.clicked.connect(self.slotDisplayA)

        self.uiDisplayB = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Display Grouped By Entity')
        self.uiDisplayB.clicked.connect(self.slotDisplayB)

        self.uiSearch = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.versionModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.versionProxyModel = VersionProxyModel()
        self.versionProxyModel.setSourceModel(self.versionModel)
        self.versionProxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.uiVersionTreeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.uiVersionTreeView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setModel(self.versionProxyModel)
        # self.uiVersionTreeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        delegate = ComboBoxDelegate(self.uiVersionTreeView)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, delegate)
        # layout
        self.displayLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.displayLayout.addWidget(self.uiDisplayA)
        self.displayLayout.addWidget(self.uiDisplayB)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(self.displayLayout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiSearch)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiVersionTreeView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        # signals/slots
        self.uiSearch.textChanged.connect(self.versionProxyModel.setFilterWildcard)
        self.slotDisplayA()


    def group_by_entity(self, items):
        grouped = {}
        for k, v in items.items():
            if not v: continue
            key = v[0].get('entity', 'unknown')
            if key not in grouped.keys():
                grouped[key] = {}
            grouped[key][k] = v
        return grouped


    def slotDisplayA(self):
        sortColumn = self.uiVersionTreeView.header().sortIndicatorSection()
        sortDirection = self.uiVersionTreeView.header().sortIndicatorOrder()
        self.versionModel.clear()
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.versionModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Entity', 'Type', 'Name', 'Versions'])


        for key, values in self.FLATLIST.items():
            col1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(values[0]['entity'])
            col2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(values[0]['type'])
            col3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(key)
            col4 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            self.versionModel.appendRow([col1, col2, col3, col4])
            col2.setData(QtGui.QColor(80,150,200), role=QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)

            col4.setData(values, QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 100)
            col4.setData(values[0], QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 101)
        # Restore
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.sortByColumn(sortColumn, sortDirection)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.expandAll()
        for i in range(self.versionModel.columnCount()):
            self.uiVersionTreeView.resizeColumnToContents(i)


    def slotDisplayB(self):
        sortColumn = self.uiVersionTreeView.header().sortIndicatorSection()
        sortDirection = self.uiVersionTreeView.header().sortIndicatorOrder()
        self.versionModel.clear()
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.versionModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Type', 'Name', 'Versions'])

        # add each entity
        ENTIYLIST = self.group_by_entity(self.FLATLIST)

        pprint.pprint(ENTIYLIST, indent=4)
        for key, values in ENTIYLIST.items():
            parent = QtGui.QStandardItem(key)
            self.versionModel.appendRow(parent)

            # add entity children
            for childKey, childValues in values.items():
                child1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(childValues[0]['type'])
                child2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(childKey)
                child3 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                parent.appendRow([child1, child2, child3])
                child1.setData(QtGui.QColor(80,150,200), role=QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)

        # Restore
        self.uiVersionTreeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.sortByColumn(sortColumn, sortDirection)
        self.uiVersionTreeView.expandAll()
        for i in range(self.versionModel.columnCount()):
            self.uiVersionTreeView.resizeColumnToContents(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I see that you are destroying and building the models every time you change the view, and I think that is not the correct way, I am thinking of creating a proxy that uses the tree type model as a source and converts it to the model of type tree and create 2 QTreeView: one with the tree model and the other with the proxy, and exchange using QStackedWidget.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand how I would do that or what you mean. If you create an example to show?

Comment: @eyllanesc because I'm not entirely sure how you would do what you are suggesting. And how to handle the comboBox only showing in correct columns.

Comment: You are only looking at the superficial problem, you should think about the case in which some QComboBox you select an item different from the first, with your methodology this is reset when you change the view.

Comment: @eyllanesc so what do you suppose i do. This is where I'm stuck and not sure how to handle it. I figure whatever solution works with this, will work if i add more options for different views in the future.

Comment: @eyllanesc using multiple TreeViews seems like a bad idea especially because if my list of items is large, it would take long to populate since it's doing it twice, one for each view, even though only one is visible.